# Capture Multiple File Names into a column on SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis

Hope you can help me.

I am looking to retrieve multiple file-names into a column from files I wish to upload onto SQL in a custom column on SSIS.

I am aware of using  Advanced Editor on the Flat File Source in Component Properties > FileNameColumnName. However, I am not sure how to make sure it picks up all the file names or what to enter in this field?

I can upload the files and all the data it holds but not the filename into a column.